# Truoble getting value from string using regex

Tags: c#, regex

Having a html string that looks like this:

```
<div class="mainClass" id="mainId" title="This is the title" customtag="+500"></div>
```

I want to get **500**

What I have done so far:

```
string k = @"<div class=""mainClass"" id=""mainId"" title=""This is the title"" customtag=""+500""></div>";
//or
string k = "<div class=\"mainClass\" id=\"mainId\" title=\"This is the title\" customtag=\"+500\"></div>";

// Using this regex (?<=customtag="\+)\d+(?=">)

Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=customtag=""\+)\d+(?="">)");
Match match = regex.Match(k);
Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

After running it, match.Value is empty even if when testing the regex in a text editor it correctly finds the string I'm looking for.

Comment: You don't need regedit for this, use substring. Better yet since it's HTML you can use HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: Your code [appears to be working](http://rextester.com/XXG4812), at least in Rextester.

Comment: Your regexp is already working perfectly http://rextester.com/KRO79101

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/xGRUGb/1

Comment: You shouldn't need to worry about capture groups here, because the two quantities in parentheses in your regex are lookarounds, which don't consume anything.  Only the `\d+` should be matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string s = "<div class=\"mainClass\" id=\"mainId\" title=\"This is the title\" customtag=\"+500\"></div>";
        Regex regex = new Regex("customtag=\"\\+(\\d+)\"");
        if (regex.Match(s).Groups.Count >= 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(regex.Match(s).Groups[1].Value);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with `XmlDocument` - IMO the cleaner way:

```
string k = "<div class=\"mainClass\" id=\"mainId\" title=\"This is the title\" customtag=\"+500\"></div>";
System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(k);
string result = doc.DocumentElement.Attributes["customtag"].Value;
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pAHXMp